# MVN isn't creating Fat Jar that is shaded

Tags: java, git, maven, jar, pom.xml

I've been trying to [install this Git repository](https://github.com/thomasjungblut/glove). I've tried to follow the instructions and I successfully `mvn clean package install` and under /target there are now 4 jar files. However, in the instructions for installation it says that

> you'll need the fat jar (glove*-shaded.jar) in the next sections.

This jar is supposed to show up after executing `mvn package`, however, its not there. Its my understanding that a fat jar just holds several different jars? And I'm guessing that the 'shaded' part comes from maven's shaded plug-in?

Comment: check if your mvn version is 3.x ?

Comment: @santiago92 yep, Apache Maven 3.0.5

Comment: try removed .m2/repository and mvn install again, for me it worked well and I created the 4 jars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shade plugin will replace the existing artifact with the shaded artifact. For this project, I see this message here:

```
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing /Users/pcsanwald/Code/glove/target/glove-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with /Users/pcsanwald/Code/glove/target/glove-0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
```

The glove*-shaded.jar file is removed afterwards, so it won't be present in your directory. The jar you're looking for will be:

```
target/glove-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

which is a shaded jar, sometimes called a "fat jar". Fat jars have all their dependencies included, so that adding additional dependencies on the classpath at runtime isn't required. you can verify that your jar contains all its dependencies by doing

```
jar -tvf target/glove-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you. I had already tried adding this Jar to my eclipse path, and some classes were not working which led me to believe I hadn't done the MVN correctly. For instance, GloveBinaryRandomAccessReader can't be resolved to a type.